# How can I merge 2 lines into a single line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I  have records like below

```
"1234", "abcg"
"456899","jklm
sd"
"34566","lmno"
```

I wants to continue second record in same line so the output will be

```
"1234", "abcg"
"456899","jklmsd"
"34566","lmno"
```

the main point is I want to continue in second line not splitting it in 2 lines

Comment: Often in CSVs like that (e.g. those exported from MS-Excel) the newline midfield is a `\n` alone while the newline at the end of each record is `\r\n`. Is that the case with yours? Do `cat -v file` and [edit] your question to include the output. If your input can contain multiple newlines mid-field then you should include that in your sample input/output. Also, see [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
awk '/^"/{printf "\n";} {printf "%s",$0}' test.csv

"1234", "abcg"
"456899","jklmsd"
"34566","lmno"
```

- `/^"/{printf "\n";}` will add a new line if line starts with double quotes.
- `{printf "%s",$0}` will remove the new line in each line.

Answer (score 0):

The `awk` method works well because of its simplicity. But it is also possible to use the stream editor, `sed` to work across multiple lines as hinted at in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed). The technique might be useful in other situations.

```
sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n([^, "]+\"\n)/\1/g' file
```

Sed has a terse command syntax. What this does is

1. Use `:a` to create a label,
2. The `N` command appends the next line,
3. Branch to our label with `$!ba`,
4. And `s` to substitute text between the `/\n(...)/`
5. The first new line, `\n`, is outside the parenthesis, so dropped.
6. `/\1/` just puts back what was inside the parenthesis.

The `[^, "]` `regex` pattern is a quick guess at finding incomplete fields. It looks for lines without commas or spaces that end in quotes, and appends them to the previous line. The file may have other inconsistencies that a simple pattern like this won't fix.

Result:

```
"1234", "abcg"
"456899","jklmsd"
"34566","lmno"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following gets rid of all embedded newlines in the second column of your CSV data using `csvjson` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to transform the data to JSON, and then `jq` to find and replace any newlines and to reformat the data as CSV again.

```
$ csvjson -H file.csv | jq -r '.[] | .b |= gsub("\n"; "") | [ .a, .b ] | @csv'
1234," ""abcg"""
456899,"jklmsd"
34566,"lmno"
```

The funky looking `" ""abcg"""` is due to the original data having embedded double quotes (they are embedded in the data rather than quoting the field due to the space before the first double quote in the field).

The `-H` option to `csvjson` tells the tool that the first row is not a header row but data.  The `jq` expression uses `.a` and `.b` for the two fields on each row.

Answer (score 0):

For fixing up the csv which has records span next line, you can make use of the `sed` editor:

```
$ sed -e '
    $!N
    /\n"/!s/\n//
    P;D
' file.csv
```

**Explanation:**

- Any line that doesn't begin with a double quote has spilled over, hence we go ahead and remove the newline so that it merges with the previous line.
- `P;D` pragma will repeat this process till the eof.
- We examine 2 lines of the csv file into the pattern space by means of the `$!N` command.

We can manipulate the output record separator in `awk` based on the input line
and get the desired output:

```
$ awk '{ORS = /"$/ ? RS : ""}1' file.csv
```